# Determining the distance across a rectangle for an arbitrary angle

Tags: geometry, rectangles

I'm trying to determine the 'diameter' or distance across a given rectangle for a given angle.  Ideally there should be a function f(theta) that takes a polar angle and determines the distance across the rectangle.

For example, with a rectangle with width `w` (from `-w/2` to `w/2`) and height `h` `(-h/2, h/2)` and centered at `(0,0)`:

`f(0)` should be the width `w`.

`f(PI/2)` should be the height `h`.

`f(atan(h / w))` should be the diagonal.

Outside of these three cases, I'm not entirely sure how to interpolate points.

- Is there a closed form solution (or approximation)? Probably not.
- Do I interpolate between those three points with a piecewise function? Probably.

  - Would such a function use linear, quadratic, or some other interpolation?  How would I determine this?

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width is the projection of the diagonal $d$ on the direction, i.e.,
$$ d \cos(\theta - \tan^{-1}\frac{h}{w}) $$

Comment: Wow.  It seems so simple!  Thank you so much!